# Other ways to search a ListView

Tags: java, android, json, listview, search

I am trying to use TextChangedListener to implement search functionality on my ListView. But after adding some character in EditText; the ListView goes blank. I have implemented filter method in my ArrayAdapter class.

I am getting my data from JSON.

My Logcat shows: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer

Is there any other way to search ListView?

Here's my code:

**UserList.java**

```
public class UserList extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<MyDataModel> list;
private MyArrayAdapter adapter;
private EditText search;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_list);

    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

    //Array List for Binding Data from JSON to this List
    list = new ArrayList<>();

    //Binding that List to Adapter
    adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, list);

    //Getting List and Setting List Adapter
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String text = search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.filter(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });


    //Checking Internet Connection
    if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
        new GetDataTask().execute();
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.parentLayout),"Internet Connection Not Available", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//Creating Get Data Task for Getting Data From Web
class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    int jIndex;
    int x;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Progress Dialog for User Interaction
        x=list.size();

        if(x==0)
            jIndex=0;
        else
            jIndex=x;

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(UserList.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Please Wait..."+x);
        dialog.setMessage("Retrieving Data");
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Getting JSON Object from Web Using okHttp
        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONParser.getDataFromWeb();

        try {

            if (jsonObject != null) {

                if(jsonObject.length() > 0) {

                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Keys.KEY_CONTACTS);

                    //Check Length of Array...
                    int lenArray = array.length();
                    if(lenArray > 0) {
                        for( ; jIndex < lenArray; jIndex++) {

                            //Creating Every time New Object and adding to List
                            MyDataModel model = new MyDataModel();

                            JSONObject innerObject = array.getJSONObject(jIndex);
                            String name = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_NAME);

                            model.setName(name);
                            list.add(model);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            Log.i(JSONParser.TAG, "" + je.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        dialog.dismiss();

        //Checking if List size if more than zero then update ListView
        if(list.size() > 0) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } else {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.parentLayout), "No Data Found", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
}
```

I have implemented the filter method in my ArrayAdapter class.

Here's my ArrayAdapter class:

**MyArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyDataModel> implements Filterable{

List<MyDataModel> modelList;
Context context;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<MyDataModel> arrayList;

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, List<MyDataModel> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    modelList = objects;

    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<MyDataModel>();
    this.arrayList.addAll(modelList);
}

@Override
public MyDataModel getItem(int position) {
    return modelList.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder vh;
    if (convertView == null) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row_view, parent, false);
        vh = ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
        view.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    MyDataModel item = getItem(position);

    vh.textViewName.setText(item.getName());
    return vh.rootView;
}


private static class ViewHolder {
    public final RelativeLayout rootView;

    public final TextView textViewName;

    private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, TextView textViewName) {
        this.rootView = rootView;
        this.textViewName = textViewName;
    }

    public static ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        return new ViewHolder(rootView, textViewName);
    }
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    modelList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        modelList.addAll(arrayList);
    } else {
        for (MyDataModel wp : arrayList) {
            if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                modelList.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: are you getting any items in 'modelList' in filter() method.???

Comment: I get entire list displayed but when I enter a character in EditText to search, the ListView vanishes and I'm not able to see the list again

Comment: but are you getting proper filtered ArrayList as you enter character??

Comment: No. When I enter a character to filter my list; I am not able to see any entry

Comment: any reason to use Locale.getDefault()???

Comment: When you create your adapter, you copy 'modelList' to 'arrayList'. Noted that both are empty. After you parse your JsonObject, you update the list (modelList) and call notifyDataSetChanged() to update the ListView. That would not update your 'arrayList', your 'arrayList' is still empty. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go with this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html), and follow steps for implementing the same:

and the problem with buffer is called every `textchanged` listener will call everytime if you add or delete any character or space in it. So avoid using that. It will cause memory leak problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
modelList = new ArrayList<MyDataModel>;
```

Write this line after  `modelList.clear();`  and check.