# custom list adapter with filter doesn't work in android

Tags: java, android, listview

hi guys i have a custom list adapter and edittext as filter, when i type anything the list disappears and nothing is being filtered

here is the filter method in the adapter class

```
 public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    DataList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        DataList.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (Electors wp : arraylist) {
            if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                DataList.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and here is where i call it in the mainactivity

```
 name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {


        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable theWatchedText) {

            String text = name.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            Vote.this.adapter.filter(text);

        }
    });
```

any suggestion for that would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Why don't you use "theWatchedText" variable that is provided by the API?

Comment: can u explain more ?https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108496/tiago-d%c3%a1vila

Comment: can u explain more https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108496/tiago-d%c3%a1vila

Comment: Put your Vote class code here for better help

Comment: May be you have the same problem like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343902/other-ways-to-search-a-listview#comment81711261_47343902 Take a look on my comment and hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Vote.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

In **onTextChanged** function.
This should work for you.

Comment: Just replace ListAdapter to SimpleAdapter or ArrayAdapter and keep everything same. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use that in onTextChanged() method as below

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //Use this below line if you want to use it in filter method from your adapter and put the below code in that method.
            //filter(editText.getText().toString());
            String text = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
            filteredList.clear();
            for (String str : arrayList){
                String name = str.toLowerCase();
                if(name.contains(text)) {
                    filteredList.add(str);
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

whereas filtered list is your DataList.